# Select SVG width using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I need to be able to select the width and height of an `svg` element inside an `embed` element using jQuery. Note that it has to be inside an embed element, if that matters to the answer.

I tried this as a test but it returns `undefined`:

```
var width = $('embed:first').children("svg:first").attr("width");
alert(width);
```

Later when I get this to work I'm going to use .each, so this is just for testing.

Some googling seems to suggest that `svg` cannot be so easily selected this way. Can someone explain exactly how to do it instead? If I need to use the jQuery SVG plugin, can you explain the usage to achieve the above, because I couldn't get that from the examples on the site.

UPDATE: Please note that the svg is embedded in an embed element with the src attribute:

```
<embed class="image" width="100%" height="100%"
               src="svgimage.svg"
                        ></embed>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just download jquery.svg.js and load it with a script element after jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.svg.js'></script>
```

To get hold of the SVG element:

```
var svg   = document.querySelector('embed').getSVGDocument().documentElement;
var width = svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'width');
console.log(width);
```

To get hold of all `embed`, use `document.querySelectorAll('embed')` instead.

Full example (must be run on server/localhost, local file wont work):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='jquery.svg.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed src="circle1.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <embed src="circle2.svg" type="image/svg+xml">

    <script>
      (function () {
        var embeds, embed, i, onSvgLoaded;

        onSvgLoaded = function () {
          var $svg;

          $svg  = $( this.getSVGDocument().documentElement );
          width = $svg.attr('width');
          console.log('Width:', width);
        };

        embeds = document.querySelectorAll('embed');

        for (i=0; embed=embeds[i]; i++) {
          embed.addEventListener('load', onSvgLoaded);
        }

      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

circle1.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

circle2.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Right, but what I need to know is how do I use it to get the width of the svg in the embed element? I have no idea...

Comment: Your code above should work. I'm fairly sure it would work even without the svg plugin.

Comment: Sorry, it seems the problem is that your svg is inside the `embed` element. If you can remove it everything should work just fine. In all modern browsers you can get away with putting the svg directly inline with the HTML.

Comment: No, it doesn't, tried with the plugin included too, no difference. Probably has something to do with the fact that the svg isn't loaded on page load, since it is embedded in the embed element. See my update...

Comment: Well, as you can see from my update, I can't remove the embed element, because that's where the svg is. All this code comes from an xml transformation, where embed is used to create svg by using the src attribute...

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution. Pls observe this only works if the svg document is from the same domain. Otherwise there is no solution.

Comment: Apparently the same problem, getting this: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('embed').getSVGDocument().documentElement'). I guess it's because the svg dom is not loaded yet, since it is in the embed element...

Comment: I had to move on so I haven't actually tried your final answer, but I did have some success with this, so I'll accept your answer and try it out more as soon as I get the chance. Thanks.